# How can i display my results for my multiple choice quiz?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a multiple choice quiz and was wondering How I would be
able to display the answers. At the moment I've got it outputting how
many answers the user got correct (1,2,3 etc). I would like it to output the 3 choices under the question headings and color the correct one in bold. Here is the code I've done so far.

```js
function check() {
  var question1 = document.quiz.question1.value;
  var question2 = document.quiz.question2.value;
  var question3 = document.quiz.question3.value;
  var correct = 0;

  if (question1 == "it") {
    correct++;
  }

  if (question2 == "stuff1") {
    correct++;
  }

  if (question3 == "stuff3") {
    correct++;
  }

  var messages = ["MLG!", "Okay...", "Git Gud"];
  var pictures = ["img/win.gif", "img/meh.gif", "img/lose.gif"];

  var range;

  if (correct < 1) {
    range = 2;
  }

  if (correct > 0 && correct < 3) {
    range = 1;
  }

  if (correct > 2) {
    range = 0;
  }

  document.getElementById("after_submit").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = messages[range];
  document.getElementById("number_correct").innerHTML = "You got " +
    correct + " correct.";
  document.getElementById("picture").src = pictures[range];
}
```

```html
<h1> Random Quiz ! </h1>
<form id="quiz" name="quiz">
  <h2> How do you spell it? </h2>
  <input id="textbox" type="text" name="question1">
  <br>
  <h3> What is the colour of the sky? </h3>
  <input type="radio" id="MCQ" name="question2" value="stuff1"> Lime Green
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="MCQ" name="question2" value="stuff2"> Neon Purple
  <br>
  <h4> Does looking at pictures of sun hurt your eyes? </h4>
  <input type="radio" id="MCQ" name="question3" value="stuff3"> Yes
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="MCQ" name="question3" value="stuff4"> Maybe...
  <br>
  <input id="BTN" type="button" value="Next" onclick="check();">
</form>

<div id="after_submit">

  <p id="message"></p>
  <p id="number_correct"></p>
  <img id="picture">
</div>
```

Comment: some html would be nice

Comment: So as i understand, all you need is to bold the right answers after thq quiz is finsihed?

Answer (score 1):

To make your code easier, you could store the questions in an array:

```
function check(){
var answers=[1,2,3].map(id=> document.quiz["question"+id]);  
var solutions=["it","stuff2", "stuff3"];
var correct=0;
for(var i=0;i<solutions.length && i<answers.length;i++){
  if(answers[i].value===solutions[i]){
     correct++;
  }else{
   alert(" No! Question "+(i+1)+" was "+solutions[i]);
  }
}
//calc range + show emoji
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I edited the code and all that showed up in an alert was "No! Question 1 was it".

Comment: @theNoobProgrammer Remember to accept the answer if you're happy with it

Comment: @james douglas: he just said he tested it. No need to remember him to accept an answer, that is not really an answer yet.

Comment: @theNoobprogrammer you need to add fieldsets around the radios and then add the class to the fieldset. Then it should work...

Comment: @Jonas w What would i have to do if i wanted to output both the alerts and  the amount of answers the user got correct?

Comment: @theNoobProgrammer edited to make it easier. In the lonterm fieldsets and classes would be the better approach, however i dont want to overhelm you with that...

Comment: @theNoobProgrammer: perfect! Glad to help ;) now its time toclose this question...